# ReduxToolkit: How to sync store change to local state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

In my component I load initial data from API like following:

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const groups = useSelector(selectGroups);
    const [localGroupState, setLocalGroupsState] = useState(groups);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(loadAsync());
    }, []);
```

```
export const selectGroups = (state: RootState) => state.userGroups.groups;
```

```
export const loadAsync = (): AppThunk => dispatch => { 
    dispatch(loading());  
    axios.get('/data', { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${getToken()}` } })
    .then((axiosResponse: AxiosResponse<MainState>) => {
        dispatch(loaded(axiosResponse.data));
        console.log('all good')
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.error('no good')
    });    
};
```

But `localGroupState` is empty but `groups` is not.
I feel like I am missing a simple trick here.
Help is really appreciated.

Comment: What's the reason you have `localGroupState`? Can you not just use `groups` in your component?

Comment: @NicholasTower I want the store to reflect all the data but I want the `localGroupState` to be able to filter and search on within the component only.

Comment: Please show all information needed to produce a minimal example, like showing `selectGroups` selector, your initial state and so on

Comment: @DennisVash updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do sorting and filtering of the groups, then your local state should be those sorting and filtering criteria. The sorted and filtered groups should be a calculated value, not a state.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const groups = useSelector(selectGroups);
const [sort, setSort] = useState('ascending');
const [filter, setFilter] = useState('something');

const sortedGroups = [...groups].sort(
  // replace this with whatever your sorting logic is
  sort === 'ascending' ? (a, b) => a - b : (a, b) => b - a
).filter(() => /* some filtering code */);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadAsync());
}, []);
```

For performance reasons, you may want to memoize the sorting and filtering, so that it only gets rerun when `groups`, `sort`, or `filter` change:

```
const sortedGroups = useMemo(() => {
  return [...groups].sort(
    // replace this with whatever your sorting logic is
    sort === 'ascending' ? (a, b) => a - b : (a, b) => b - a
  ).filter(() => /* some filtering code */);
}, [groups, sort, filter]);
```